# Ext filesystem: what happens if a journal is replayed after a crash

Tags: filesystems, ext4, journaling

I read some things about the ext filesystem journaling, including the man pages, but still do not fully grasp the mechanism.

What exactly happens with data and metadata when replaying a journal with e2fsck after a crash?
What is different if the journal_data option is enabled?
Are there differences between ext3 and ext4?

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a detailed paper on the implementation of the journal layer:

http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/journal-design.pdf